# How to find distance metrics in python

Tags: python

This is the array.

```
arr=[1,2,2,1,5,1]
```

i need to calculate the abs value of index differences between in and all the other elements if the same value, like explained below.

```
distance metric for a[0] = |0-3|+|0-5|=8
distance metric for a[1] = |1-2|=1
distance metric for a[2] = |2-1|=1
distance metric for a[3] = |3-0|+|3-5|=5
distance metric for a[4] = 0
distance metric for a[5] = |5-0|+|5-3|=7
```

output is

```
[8,1,1,5,0,7]
```

can someone help in coding this in python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this working example:

```
arr=[1,2,2,1,5,1]
res = []
for i, n in enumerate(arr):
    val = 0
    occur = [j for j, x in enumerate(arr) if x == n and j != i]
    for o in occur:
        val += abs(i-o)
    res.append(val)
print(res)
```

> [8, 1, 1, 5, 0, 7]

a bit more efficient version with a complexity of O(n**2)

```
arr=[1,2,2,1,5,1]
res = []
for i, n in enumerate(arr):
    val = 0
    for j, x in enumerate(arr):
        if x == n and j != i:
            val += abs(i-j)
    res.append(val)
print(res)
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service @Jennie

Comment: I agree, but I needed to clean my head with this nice little exercise, and if I can help someone …It ain't that horrible (:

Comment: it was mainly meant to the OP

Comment: I'll do anything to avoid writing my Msc theses

Comment: is there a way to decrease the execution time @Green

Comment: You can calculate val inside of the for loop, in the list comprehension

Comment: I add an example of a bit more efficient  version, you can make it more efficient using numpy. but I guess it would be an overkill

Comment: val += abs(i-o) , here o is undefined @Green

Comment: I did it on the fly...it's `j`...but I would learn what is `enumerate` in python if I were you.

Comment: this function really iam not aware of, i will dig more deep into it. And can you help me how can we write the same in numpy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228055/discussion-between-jennie-and-green).

Answer (score 5):

Using list comprehensions and avoiding intermediate variables

```
arr = [1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1]

output = []
for index in range(len(arr)):
    output.append(sum(abs(index - k) if arr[k] == arr[index] else 0 for k in range(len(arr))))

print(output)
```